# "Unregistered Device" is 100% active during connected standby

Tags: windows-8.1, sleep

I have an Intel-based tablet (Lenovo Miix 2 8) running Windows 8.1. Overnight, while sleeping, the battery level drops significantly (>20% is ~8 hours). I ran `powercfg /sleepstudy`, and see the following:

```
NAME                          | TYPE      | % ACTIVE TIME | ACTIVE TIME
Unregistered Device \_SB.I2C3 | Fx Device | 100%          | 3:55:46
```

This has been going on for some time now, although I don't recall exactly when. (And `/batteryreport` doesn't help, either. What can be done about this? Thank you!

**EDIT:** In device manager, I found six "Intel Atom I2C Controller" devices. They are `I2C1`, `I2C2`, and `I2C3` through `I2C7`. No `I2C3`. Any ideas? Thank you!

**EDIT 2:** Reinstalling Windows did not help. :(

Comment: Kinda sounds like a USB port controller, but I can't find anything in a quick Google (other than 30 sites that want to give you driver downloads).

Comment: @DanielRHicks I came across [this](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Idea-Windows-based-Tablets-and/Miix-2-8-Battery-Drain-Unregistered-Device-SB-I2C3-under-Fx/td-p/1595920) on the Lenovo forum. Unfortunately, the download links posted there go elsewhere. I'm fairly sure it's not a good idea to download a bios off some third-party site...